# Count number of times a date appears in a list to pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Given a list of dates:

```
a = ['2013-12-14', '2013-12-14', '2013-12-24', '2013-12-25', '2013-12-25', '2013-12-25']
```

I want to calculate a pandas timeseries by counting the occurrence of each date:

```
2013-12-14 2
2013-12-15 0
2013-12-16 0
...
2013-12-24 1
2013-12-25 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are these strings? (a list of strings?)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to datetime64 wit to_datetime then use value_counts and resample:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime(a)
Out[11]:
DatetimeIndex(['2013-12-14', '2013-12-14', '2013-12-24', '2013-12-25',
               '2013-12-25', '2013-12-25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(a).value_counts()
Out[12]:
2013-12-25    3
2013-12-14    2
2013-12-24    1
dtype: int64

In [13]: pd.to_datetime(a).value_counts().resample('D').sum()
Out[13]:
2013-12-14    2
2013-12-15    0
2013-12-16    0
2013-12-17    0
2013-12-18    0
2013-12-19    0
2013-12-20    0
2013-12-21    0
2013-12-22    0
2013-12-23    0
2013-12-24    1
2013-12-25    3
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thx so much! Very helpful~